# Why do we have Kosher L'Pesach quinoa but not buckwheat (kasha)?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Neither of the two [pseudocereal grains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocereal) I've seen used frequently for consumption,[quinoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinoa) and [buckwheat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwheat), are one of the 5 grains that can become chametz. I know that for many years, quinoa was banned, but in the past few years, some kosher agencies (OU for one) have allowed using quinoa. Yet no one has allowed using buckwheat on Pesach, AFAIK.

Both quinoa and buckwhet look like grains or "seeds". But have they still placed buckwheat in the *kitniyot* category, but not quinoa? If so, why? What's the difference with these two grains that allows one but not the other?

Comment: The strongest reason to allow quinoa is because it was only 'found' recently, therefore no minhag exists to not use it. An old world item that was not clearly used always has that door open to say aha! we didn't and shouldn't use it!

Comment: Source for [buckwheat](https://translate.google.com/#yi/en/%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A2) being included in kitniyot: [M"B 453:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.453.4). I don't know his source (more precisely than what he says there: "*acharonim*") or how its approach to buckwheat is differentiable from quinoa.

Comment: re "for many years, quinoa was banned": I've never heard of this. I also don't see anything like that [here](http://ohr.edu/5390) or from an online search. Can you substantiate it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

People have attempted all sorts of mental gymnastics to develop a Theory of Everything vis-a-vis kitniyot.

I spare my poor brain and follow Rav Moshe Feinstein's opinion (Igros, OC3:63): it's kitniyot if it happened to have been banned (or "warned against"); not if it didn't. Rav Moshe also suspects that at some point they stopped adding foods to the list of kitniyot, as otherwise there would be nothing left to eat! (This is certainly historically possible. It's also Rav Moshe projecting how he would approach the problem.)

Otherwise, asks Rav Moshe, explain to me why *mustard* was on the list 700 years ago, yet *caraway* was clearly not on the list as of 200 years ago?

So why buckwheat and not quinoa? Because buckwheat was known to Ashkenazic rabbis a few centuries ago, and quinoa was not. So they never developed a ban or warning about it.

If, instead, we look for categorical explanations, then [several could be offered](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/QuonfusedAboutQuinoa/), e.g.:

- Buckwheat and wheat can grow in the same field and therefore there is a cross-contamination risk, whereas quinoa is grown at such high altitudes that wheat couldn't grow there.
- "Buckwheat" is a word that people can confuse with "wheat", but "quinoa" is not.
- Quinoa's closest commonly-eaten relative is the beet, which everyone eats on Passover.

---

As for what's happened with quinoa in the past few years: there have been legitimate questions of cross-contamination in the factories and how it's processed. But assuming you know this is 100% pure quinoa, some poskim felt (and feel) that it is so grainlike that it should be prohibited, or it was already covered under some sort of categorical ban. (Some even attempted to split hairs and say it's so grainlike, even Rav Moshe would consider it prohibited; in my humble opinion that's a forced reading.) The Star-K has vociferously allowed it. There were differences of opinion among OU poskim, and my understanding is that recently, there was some change of thought among them to shift the official OU position from `ask your posek, we're not commenting` to `it will say OU-P, and if your custom is otherwise, then follow your custom.` I believe someone approached the OU poskim with the categorical arguments.

Comment: Re: confusion based on name: I've been thinking about for years but never gotten around to writing a Purim Torah devar Halacha on the category of "אף על פי שאין בה ממש חמץ, יש בה שם חמץ", including things like fire crackers, sweetbreads, etc. Are you suggesting that such a category actually exists?

Comment: +1 just for the record Rabbi Belsky is personally very much against using quinoa on Pesach. But the OU uses their voting system for their policies.

Comment: @IsaacMoses a certain rabbi who's no longer zachur latov published something on Kitniyot in 2013 where he suggested this, especially with regards to "corn." He cited other places in halacha where the common name makes a difference. (E.g. azlinan batar shma in maachalot asurot).

Comment: @user6591 yes my understanding is that Rabbis Genack or Schachter rethought their opinon, and this achieved *acharei rabim lehatot* against Rabbi Belsky.

Comment: @Shalom I think Rabbi Schachter was quoted a long time ago as permitting quinoa, so we probably know who the swing voter was. But who are you quoting about corn? I don't know if I should admit it, but I thought the same thing! Maize is very similar to masa! In fact a plate full of sfardi finger food like lachmagine kibbe cigars etc is referred to as a whole by the term mazeh.

Comment: @user6591 "corn" was the old English term for any grain, including wheat; you'll find it in the King James Bible for instance. I'm quoting the subject of http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-mikvah-scandal-could-happen-thought.html

Comment: @Shalom ah so B.F. said it? And he focused on the old English word? I was focusing on the Spanish, which is basically the same yisod, but mine had a pircha, the Spanish speaking peoples don't abstain from kitnios:)

Comment: As stated in the comment, a lot happens when I'm away for a few hours. This is a simple but well phrased response. I think that what you have raised is that kitniyot is a confusing process. Since you mentioned R. Moshe - I believe he said that peanuts were not kitniyot. In the 60's and 70's OU placed their hashgacha on Planter's peanut oil for Pesach use by everyone. At some point, peanuts became kitniyot again. So, who or what determines this override?

Comment: @DanF Rav Moshe said there was no custom against peanuts where he came from, and if you knew of no family custom, you could eat peanuts. He was okay with an OU-P peanut oil, with the understanding that if your custom was to avoid peanuts, you wouldn't buy it. My understanding is that enough Jews had a tradition against peanuts (Rav Yitzchak Elchanan Spector did, and I think most Hassidim do) that it wasn't worth the OU's headache as too large a percentage of their clientele didn't accept it. I heard a rabbi from the OK say that personally he still eats peanuts on pesach.

Answer (score -1):

Coffee beans are allowed, as well as cocoa beans. They are really a fruit od a plant, just like Kasha. If we don't call it buckweat but instead Kasha there is no confusion.

String beans or green beans are allowed because its a vegetable, not a legume. They both have the word bean in it to confuse it with a legume.

Comment: Hey Rachel welcome to the site! Consider improving this answer by editing in a source regarding the parameter of classes of foods included in kitniyot. If this is something that you heard , you can mention where you heard it. To lean more about the site, including what sorts of questions and answers are encouraged consider seeing [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help). For a brief tour of the site, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you choose to stick around the site.